# Is is possible to set out parameter while signal an error for MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want my stroed procedure both set out paramters to NULL and error message if excution failed. Here is my approach:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p(OUT outp INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      SET outp = NULL;
      RESIGNAL; -- without resignal output is set.
   END;

   START TRANSACTION;
      SELECT id INTO outp FROM some_table WHERE some_condition;
      IF outp IS NULL THEN
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'outp is null';
      ELSE 
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'outp not null';
      END IF;
   COMMIT;
END
```

The test code is:

```
SET @id = 987;
CALL p(@id);
SELECT @id;
```

With resignal statement on line 7, the error message pops but @id remains 987.
Without reginal statement on line 7, @id is set to NULL but no error messages.

Is it possible to do both?

Comment: This is some really strange MySQL. What's the purpose of all this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's just a sample. Not accrual code. What I want to achieve is acknowledge the client program if the procedure calling is success by it output value, and provide more information if an error do occur.